# What is the best way to fill a dropdown with values depending on first dropdown in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I could of course do a select after the first i selected but that seems to give a lot of overhead.

Would populating a hashmap with the different tables be best or what is the best course of action to solve this.

In my case I have a list of clubs with a number of members (players). After selecting club I would like to only have the members associated with that club to be visible.

you can see the solution here.
http://score.megahooked.com/BowlingFacelets/faces/hcp/club.xhtml

Comment: Are the clubs and members in different dropdowns ? Also, any code to show ?

Comment: You can see the solution at the link I have added. the code is pretty standard JPA with a club class and a service Class for handling the add/delete etc. The club has the normal JPA stuff and also the equals/Hash for bean. It also has a converter. So the question is more on a conceptual level. Of course if you have code for a best practice solution it's great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fetching all the data from the DB at once, you can

1. Store the data as club/list of member pairs in a map
2. Populate the first drop down with just the keys of the map.
3. On selecting a key, get its values from the map and populate the second drop down.

If you are fetching only the clubs from the DB to start off with, you can

1. Populate the first drop down with the club names
2. Depending on your selection, query and fetch the member names from the DB
3. Populate the second drop down with the member names.

Comment: My question was what is the best practice. Not you can do this or that.

Comment: And that is exactly what I have written

Comment: It depends on how you fetch the data. Depending on the data fetching mechanism, I have suggested the two best ways

Comment: Yes but what is the prefered data fetching mechanism from a load standpoint? What is the most efficient way?

Comment: If there is a lot of data, the second method. If the data is not much, one DB call to fetch all the data would be better. In that case, the population of the drop downs would be quicker.